# Exporting Eclipse project with a reference to native library

Tags: java, eclipse, export, project, native

I have an Eclipse project, that uses JMF, I found out I could skip the JMF installation process and still to use the CaptureDeviceManager of the JMF, and to receive the list of devices if I could point my project to the native lib of the JMF.

I've managed to add the native lib to the IDE run/debug, but once I export the application to an external runnable Jar, the application cannot find the native lib.

the files are located in c:\JMF*.dll

I tried to add the folder path to the environment variable in windows - didn't work.

I tried to add them into another Jar and add it to the project - didn't work.

I tried to add the files into the project - didn't work.

I tried to add the path to the class path - didn't work.

I tried to add the path to the library path - didn't work.

does someone have any sort of a solution?

Thanks in advance,
Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at this:
[How to capture video using JMF, but without installing JMF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046621/how-to-capture-video-using-jmf-but-without-installing-jmf/5552395#5552395)

It's probably doing what you need.

Comment: I think this will do, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I have been using the JOGL graphics libraries for the last few years. It bundles dlls into jars which eclipse then uses in executing the project as well as when the project is exported as a runnable jar. Not sure what they are doing but it works just fine with eclipse as well as with the JDotSoft jar-in-jar class loader.

Recently I tried to bundle another library into the project, by Phidget. I can include the jar and its dlls in eclipse, and execute the app just fine from inside eclipse. However, when I export the project as an executable jar the dlls are NOT included in the resulting jar and, of course, the jar fails to run because it can't find the dlls. In this case, it finds the JOGL dlls, but not the Phidget ones, even though I use the same mechanism within eclipse to associate the dlls with their respective jars.

In the second case I tried manually adding the dlls to the exported jar but that did not work (perhaps it is because of the way Phidget loads their libraries).

I suspect that this may be a bug in Eclipse and plan to submit it as one unless someone else can offer more insight into the problem of native libraries sometimes not be exported by Eclipse into an executable jar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bot says to provide more info ....

Create a java project that depends on a java jar and an accompanying native library (dll). Associate the har qirh the oroject, and the library with the jar. Confirm the project runs.

Now export the project as an executable jar. Try to run the jar. Note that it complains about a missing library. Look in the executable jar. Note that it does not contain the library.