# required jars for video recording using JMF

Tags: java, applet, jmf

which are the jars used to record video from the list of jar files

1)jmf.jar
2)multiplayer.jar
3)mediaplayer.jar
4)sound.jar
5)customizer.jar

i am trying to record a video using an applet which contains JMF class,when i tried this applet in a system which doesnt have JMF installed i am not getting any video and audio properties like in a system which has JMF installed.how can i get video and audio properties in an applet in a system which has no JMF installed

currently i am adding only jmf.jar,i have to add all these libraries for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one you need to add to the classpath and deploy with your application is JMF.jar. It contains all the classes you will need to record video.

As for getting the audio and video properties, you have two options. The first is to require or instruct the user to install JMF before they can use your applet. I don't think this is what you want. The other is to set up the client machine manually to use JMF. The underlying a/v processing is handled by a set of dll's on windows and .so's on linu/unix. You can actually check out my other post for using the video recording properties of JMF without it being installed: [located here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046621/how-to-capture-video-using-jmf-but-without-installing-jmf)

You'll need to perform the copying of the dlls and initalize the jmf.properties file before you can perform any video recording on the client.

Comment: hi user489041 i am not getting those .dll(except jsound.dll) files as given in the above link when i downloaded jmf for windows i got one exe file , and ,can u sent me JMF Source code and also also JMFinit.java
JMRPropertiesGen.java  to "evanhackborn@gmail.com" thanks for the reply

Comment: Sure thing, their on their way. You need to actually install jmf on you machine to get the dll's. They get placed in the win32 folder. Thats where I grabbed them from. Sorry for the confusion on that.