# JMF Cannot find video.properties file

Tags: java, webcam, jmf

My code doesn't find it when trying to create a FrameGrabber. When I did a search for it in Explorer, it wasn't found. Is there something obvious I need to do to generate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added **JMF.jar** file in CLASSPATH!
check this Question [how-to-capture-video-using-jmf-but-without-installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046621/how-to-capture-video-using-jmf-but-without-installing-jmf) for configuring JMF.
and [required-jars-for-video-recording-using-jmf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079929/required-jars-for-video-recording-using-jmf).
will help you sort your problem.