# How to play other video formats in JavaFX

Tags: java, video, javafx-2, media, avi

I am busy with a movie/video-clip player/library.

I want to do this in JavafX. Almost 90% of the video clips is in AVI format. I cannot for several reasons covert the movies/video-clips.

I also want the program to mark the video files that were played, from start to complete, so that I will know what have been watched. So the program needs to be able to interact with the video player to know when the video has played to the end.

JavafX doesn't allow playback for AVI files. What's the alternative to be able to use this with? And how will I know if the video has fully played from beginning to end.

I read the following 
[Adding other video codecs / DVD support to JavaFX 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153227/adding-other-video-codecs-dvd-support-to-javafx-2-2)

Where they suggest I use portable VLC player. Is this the best way to use it in JavafX and if possible does the API have register hooks to register a method that can be triggered to know when the video has stopped?

Comment: What type of video and audio codecs are in these AVI files? Many codecs, or are they consistent throughout the corpus?

Comment: There might a few but it would be only a handful. I downloaded GSpot to give specific names
And this seems to be the norm codec seems to be XVid (a few AVC1) but I would be more than happy I can just get the XVid ones to work.

Comment: @Chrispie If you want to compile additional gstreamer plugins into JFX this is (relatively) involved but not impossible: http://berry120.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/expanding-javafxs-media-support.html

Comment: @berry120 Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. I will check it out and let you know how it went :)