# JavaFX : MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : media type not supported

Tags: java, video, javafx, media-player

I need to play the `3gp`, `mov` and `mp4` videos in the media player. Right now I am using JavaFx media player but it supports only `mp4` videos. So what I can do to play the other two formats as well in this player or is there any other solution also available for this. Any help and suggestions please?

jdk = 1.7

JavaFx: 2.1

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes) is a list of JavaFX supported audio and video formats.

For anything unsupported by JavaFX, you have the option of either converting them to another format or finding a way to decode them inside your application.

There are libraries available for decoding, such as [JCodec](http://jcodec.org/) or [Jffmpeg](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/)

You will need to do some further research to determine your exact requirements and which formats you will need to support. Some solutions are more difficult than others.

Answer (score 1):

The supported media types can be viewed on this page: [Introduction to JavaFX Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm)

Quoting:

> **Video:** FLV containing VP6 video and MP3 audio; MPEG-4 multimedia container with H.264/AVC (Advanced Video Coding) video compression

What you may do is convert your videos to `.flc` or `.mp4` and you will be able to play them with JavaFX `MediaPlayer`.

Related StackOverflow questions:

[Adding other video codecs / DVD support to JavaFX 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153227/adding-other-video-codecs-dvd-support-to-javafx-2-2)

[How to play other video formats in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756809/how-to-play-other-video-formats-in-javafx)

Comment: is there any library available to convert the videos to .mp4 format.??

Comment: Copy that exact quesiton to Google.