# How to play video with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I create java application in IntelliJ not JavaFx Application. After that, I import all javaFX library into project.
 I try to play video with this code.

```
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        String path = new File("C:/Users/PC/Downloads/My_video.mov").getAbsolutePath();

        Media pick = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(pick);
        player.play();
    }
}
```

when I run it show error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : Unrecognized file signature!
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:411)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

How to play video with JavaFX ?

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378999/javafx-mediaexception-media-unsupported-media-type-not-supported

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you need to extend your "Main" class with the "Application" class. Then, in the "main" method, you will only paste the following one line of code:

launch(args);

Else code will be removed from the "main" method.

You can follow the following link:

https://www.javatpoint.com/javafx-playing-video

Hope that answers your question.