# How to improve MediaView so that it can play more video extensions JavaFX

Tags: javafx, media-player

I use JavaFX MediaView to play video files. But sometimes when i play a video my application crashes even without opportunity handle some exception. But before crash i have time to get media exception: `mediaPlayer.getError().printStackTrace()` and as a result:

```
MediaException: UNKNOWN : [com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer@3c63af0d] ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID: ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153227/adding-other-video-codecs-dvd-support-to-javafx-2-2) goes into more detail. It was asked during JavaFX 2 but I believe it would still apply to JavaFX 8, 9, and 10. A comment on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959282/how-can-i-use-gstreamer-in-javafx-videoplayer) seems to support that belief.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you, I will study this issue in this direction.