# Best/simplest media framework for java

Tags: java, frameworks, media

I'm going to make a really really simple program in java. The program is just going to display a video running fullscreen in an eternal loop, and do a playback of a soundfile on a mousebutton event.

The problem is that I dont't seem to find an easy way to just play a videofile in java. Most of the frameworks seem old.

What framework would you suggest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with video (DVDs, .avi .mkv) in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669384/dealing-with-video-dvds-avi-mkv-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [xuggle](http://xuggle.com/) or [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/). Both are actively supported. JMF is still ok for certain projects.