# Play a video in Java without installation

Tags: java, swing, xuggler, vlcj

I am creating a Desktop application that has to play a video inside a frame.When i googled it out, lot of people suggested vlcj or Xuggler. Which one of these will be best to use? Some of the features that should be supported are:

1. Camera support
2. Player should be resizable dynamically.
3. Most of the formats should be supported.
4. Should run in all platforms.
5. No installation required.

For vlcj should vlc be installed in the machine?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Either should do the trick. VLC will be far easier and to work with, whereas Xuggler is more suited for advanced media control, and as such it is harder to work with. See this question/answer for a comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6905409/1270000

, For vlcj you do not need to be install vlc on the machine, you just need to bundle the relevant vlc library files with your application.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using xuggler as it has a huge codec library supporting almost all formats which is due to its dependence on FFMPEG in C and connected to Java using Swig. 
If you require all the features of ffmpeg, build xuggler in your system using the source code and not just download the jar, though it is sufficient for smaller needs.