# Java SDK for converting video to mp3

Tags: java, android, video, sdk, mp3

I wonder if there is a JAVA SDK that I can use for converting avi, video format, to mp3. I am trying to build an app in Android or BlackBerry OS 5 - 7.1 that can convert video to mp3. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An avi is a [container format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format) not a video format. It can hold a number of different video and audio formats.

The best bet would be to extract the audio stream and convert that to MP3.

See this question for more details on dealing with these in java:
[Dealing with video (DVDs, .avi .mkv) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669384/dealing-with-video-dvds-avi-mkv-in-java)