# Java, Grabbing frames from video

Tags: java, bufferedimage, video-processing

I have made a class that can take and image and read a pixel at a certain coordinate, using `BufferedImage`. Is there a way to grab a frame from a video and use `BufferedImage` to find the pixel value? or is there something like `BuffereImage` for video

Comment: Probably. But you'll need to post your current code, and what webcam library are you using?

Comment: To make things easier i will just use a prerecorded video. My question is how to grab a frame.

Comment: That makes it harder. What library are you using to open and play the prerecorded video?

Comment: Have you considered OpenCV? http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html

Comment: dont try to make your own code to do that, on source forge and google code and opencv there are libs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669384/dealing-with-video-dvds-avi-mkv-in-java

Comment: and http://www.quora.com/Java-programming-language/What-is-the-best-open-source-Video-Conferencing-api-that-would-run-on-a-Java-Client did u google before posting this question?

Comment: yes, i have seen a lot of opencv examples.But i need something that works with java 1.3.