# Any Video rendering libraries for JOGL that doesn't use JMF?

Tags: java, video, 3d, jogl, jmf

I've seen MovieGL, but that uses JMF. I would like to avoid JMF because it seems to not work unless a client actually installs it. What are my options?

Edit: this must be cross-platform and must work in win, mac and linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[packet-multibroadcaster](http://code.google.com/p/packet-multibroadcaster/) sounds like it would work, though I have not tested it.

> ... a library that was inspired by Java capturing and encoding libraries (such as JOGL, JxCapture, and Xuggler's Xuggler) and the need as a developer to be able to loosely implement any combination of these to create a multi-capture / multi-encode system without the complication of dealing with thread management.
>
> In layman's terms this means, you can
>   implement any Java capture and/or
>   encoding methodology you want and
>   loosely let them communicate.

One of the options available within packet-multibroadcaster is [xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/), which I have used and find to be very good.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently taking a look at the Xuggler. Looks promising. packet-multiX seems more to me like an encoding/capturing framework than a decoding/playback. Will relay results soon.

Comment: Yup Xuggler is awesome. I can now play videos in my JOGL scene. You gotta get a bufferedimage from it, turn that to TextureData using TextureIO, and then update the video polygon with the textureData. . . for each frame.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post out for using JMF without requiring the end user to explicitly install it [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046621/how-to-capture-video-using-jmf-but-without-installing-jmf).

Also check out VLCJ [Link](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/)

Comment: Thanks but those 2 are more for windows and/or linux. I was looking for something cross-platform.