# how To detect JMF in os

Tags: jmf

```
      how to detect JMF plugin in OS
```

is there any way to install JMF plugin siliently ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

JMF does have a silent install mode actually.  You'd need to determine the proper OS version, download the installer and launch it with the silent installer flags.

A little googling turns up: http://www.thatsjava.com/java-tech/21950/

OS independent version is easier, you can either override the classloader, or download the JAR to one of the extension directories (see the java system properties to find out where these are)

Do I need to mention that all of these take administrative permissions, which aren't going to be available to you without extra steps on anything Vista+ or anything Unix. (including OS X)

Another question might have a more useful answer: [How to capture video using JMF, but without installing JMF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046621/how-to-capture-video-using-jmf-but-without-installing-jmf)