# Detect JMF plugin In Operating System

Tags: jmf

How to detect JMF plugin in the operating system and If JMF is not install in Operating System So How To Install JMF in Operating System Silently. i need to check that jmf is installed or not.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[How to capture video using JMF, but without installing JMF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046621/how-to-capture-video-using-jmf-but-without-installing-jmf). All JMF instaler does is copy files and detect your cameras. This link can mock it out.