# How to detect a Laptop Web Camera device Using java 

Tags: java, jsp, video, streaming, jmf

I am using JMF . I am not able to detect my Laptop Web Camera device using java code . Can anybody help me in doing this ?.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to check [this](http://fmj-sf.net/) site.It should help you

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt directly say it, but the code and explanation is in there. Or just use JMF Registry that gets installed with JMF.

[How to capture video using JMF, but without installing JMF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046621/how-to-capture-video-using-jmf-but-without-installing-jmf)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Capture()
{

    di = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice("vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0");

    ml = new MediaLocator("vfw://0");

    try {
        player=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
        win.getContentPane().add(player.getVisualComponent(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        player.start();

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```